# CSS changes with focus attribute on input field

Tags: css, forms

I am trying affect the label whenever the input is focused. For whatever reason the css isnt being recognized for the label whenever the input is focused.

```
li.sm-vol label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #462770;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

li.sm-vol input:focus li.sm-vol label {
    top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML as reference? It would help understand the code and how it behaves.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with pure CSS only if the label is next to the input field by using `+` or `~` selector, i.e.

```css
input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<label>Label</label>
```

For visually reordering the input and label positions, see the simple demo with flexbox.

```css
.fieldset {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.fieldset label {
  order: -1;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.fieldset input:focus + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
  <input type="text">
  <label>Label</label>
</div>
```